# What to choose in terms of database for an Android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create an Android app similar to google latitude and I am not sure what to use in terms of databases. I thought of using SQLite (which is serverless), but I still need a server in order to make two clients communicate to each other. I am really new with connecting  an app with a server or a database, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need both. In most scenarios in Android, you can't assume the user is always with the network and hence the Local Data store is important; it's up to your application whether the user's data need to sync to server or not. As you said, a server is needed for p2p communication

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful, I think I'm on the right path now.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe there is a way to remote connect to any database from Android (could be wrong, but when I check it wasnt possible). Your going to have to use SQLite for your local, and i recommend using MySQL for the server side, and use JSON to retrieve information via a service page.

Answer (score 0):

OK, what you want to do is a client-server architecture. You need to think about what kind of data you want to store, and where to do that.

- Obviously, on the **server side**, you need to store data. It will depends what your server is, and what technology you use for it. This question has nothing to do with Android, as you'll probably communicate to your server using HTTP or another protocol that would allow it to communicate to your android app (the client) and maybe later on, to different kind of clients (web app, iOS, etc.). So you can use any database technology, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, whatever. You can even build your server application using Microsoft .NET technology, or anything else. You're not tied to Java / Android (although my personal technology stack of choice would probably be a Jetty HTTP server, Oracle database or MySQL if you want lighter, and Java of course).
- On the **client side**, you may also want some data storage, and in this case it depends on the size and complexity of what you want to store. For simple key-value pairs, use `SharedPreferences`. For more complex data structures, `SQLite` is your technology of choice.